# Multidimensional Javascript Array to Php Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 pages.

**berechnungseingabe.php**

where I generate a Multidimensional Javascript Array

```
Array[19]
3: Array[0]
7: Array[0]
11: Array[0]
      Anzahl: "1"
      Driving: 2380
      Index: "13"
      Latitude: 48.0078390267396
      Longitude: 16.224982738494873
      Walking: 1647
13: Array[0]
14: Array[0]
...
x: Array[0]
```

when i chlick on the Button

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-icon-action" onclick="berechnenDerWege()">Berechnen</button>
```

I want to send the array to the

```
berechnungsergebniss.php
```

that I can use it as php array on this page.

Is there a way with jQuery, JavaScript,PHP?

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```

does not work because I get:

**[[],null,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]**

as result.

Comment: ever heard of [**`$.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to do it with $.ajak. can you post me a code example? pleas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, yes.
JSON exists to share objects easly.

In your function call berechnenDerWege() you must encode your array to JSON with javascript.

```
JSON.stringify(myArray)
```

It will output you a string that you can pass to your PHP script through Ajax or a direct link. It depends of your implementation.

**Example without Ajax** :

```
function berechnenDerWege() {
   var myArray = [1,2,3,[5,6,7]];
   document.location.href='berechnungsergebniss.php?data='+JSON.stringify(myArray);
}
```

To decode data with PHP use json_decode().

**berechnungsergebniss.php** :

```
<?php $data = json_decode($_GET['data']); 
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: I get this as result
array(12) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> array(0) { } [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'path/to/berechnungseingabe.php',
    data : {array : JSON.stringify(yourArray)},
    complete : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And on server side:

```
$yourArray = json_decode($_POST['array']);
echo $yourArray;
```

Comment: In the complet function, how do I load the berechnungseingabe.php page because there I want to use the array.